# Laravel - install Levare modules

Tags: php, module, laravel

Hello how can I create and use modules in laravel ?

I read this: https://github.com/LevareCMS/modulemanager#how-to-use but it doesn't work.

when I put into console: `php artisan config:publish app/modules` then I see error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException] Configuration not found.
```

Everything I created like in above information.

Second question: How can I generate new modules ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

There is an error when publishing config files, change **app** for **levare**

```
php artisan config:publish levare/modules
```